# HTML div comment box with arrow

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create a comment box with an arrow. I am using the CSS, but I have a problem that I cannot solve.

I have a white background, and I need to make my comment box with a white background. So, to make the box visible to the users, I need to put a border to the box, but I don't know how to put the border to the arrow.

Here is my CSS:

```
body {background: grey;padding: 40px}

.comment_div {
    background: white;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
}

.pointer {
    border: solid 20px transparent;
    border-right-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 40px 0 0 -38px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="pointer"></div>
<div class="comment_div">
    test testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest test
    test testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest test
    test testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest test
    test testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest testtest test
</div>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zaukt/1157/).

How can I make a border to the box like below?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my solution, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RxxLG/). I hope everyone can get advantage of it.

```
.left {
    width: 920px !important;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    min-height: auto !important;
    padding-right: 0;
    float: left;
}

.left > p:first-of-type {
    background: #ffd987;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.tip {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}

.tip:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -14px;
    left: 98px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 14px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 14px solid #fff;
    border-left: 14px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    content: '';
}

.tip:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    left: 99px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 12px solid #fff;
    border-left: 12px solid transparent;
    content: '';
}

.tip.left:before {
    border-top: 14px solid transparent;
    border-right: 14px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
    border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    left: -28px;
    top: 20px;
}

.tip.left:after {
    border-top: 12px solid transparent;
    border-right: 12px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
    left: -24px;
    top: 22px;
}

<div style="padding:50px">

<div class="tip left">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam consectetur quam a sapien egestas eget scelerisque lectus tempor. Duis placerat tellus at erat pellentesque nec ultricies erat molestie. Integer nec orci id tortor molestie porta. Suspendisse eu sagittis quam.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam consectetur quam a sapien egestas eget scelerisque lectus tempor. Duis placerat tellus at erat pellentesque nec ultricies erat molestie. Integer nec orci id tortor molestie porta. Suspendisse eu sagittis quam.
</div>
```

Comment: explaining your approach with some comments would've been nice

Answer (score 2):

This site provides a really simple way to generate the CSS for you. Just choose which side you want the arrow on and the CSS is created.

http://www.cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to only support modern browsers, you can use CSS3's psuedo `::before` element.

http://jsfiddle.net/26Lww/177/

Comment: I never used that. I ll look into it

Comment: but I need the arrow to left

Comment: @Borsel This should be easy to change. I've provided the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you might have a look at [this](http://www.dreamtemplate.com/dreamcodes/documentation/comment_boxes.html) page.

```
<!-- DC Comment Boxes Start -->
<div class="tsc_clean_comment">
  <div class="avatar_box"> <img src="http://pimg.co/p/52x52" alt="Avatar" class="avatar" />
    <p class="username">Joe Blogs</p>
  </div>
  <div class="comment_box fr">
    <p class="comment_paragraph" contenteditable="true">This field is completely editable. To disable this feature remove the "contenteditable=true" tag from this code.</p>
    <a href="#" class="reply">Reply</a> <span class="date">1st January 2020</span> </div>
  <div class="tsc_clear"></div>
</div>
<!-- DC Comment Boxes End -->
```

Answer (score -2):

A simple way to do it is to make the box as an image. Use it as a background image, and a little margin-left so the text is inside the box.

Comment: I thought of that but I want to do it with real css

Comment: why? it just make the code a lot complex,and if your image is not that big(10ko for that is huge) it will not affect at all the performances

Comment: I totally agree with @wazaminator . There is no use of doing this kind of things in css. It wont support older broswers and it more complex the na image.

Comment: -1 I disagree. You shouldn't need an image for something as simple as this. At the cost of old browsers you are adding an extra HTTP request & restricting text size increase. I'd rather have new techniques in new browsers, than be stuck in the past because some users continue to use old software. At very most this should be a fallback using modernizr etc. Even then, why make the whole box an image?? You could just make the arrow an image.

Comment: @Curt, I have done it and put on Fiddle. Would you mind checking it?